# Java сравнивание времени

Tags: java, android, время

Такой вопрос: есть строка например 08:15-09:50(время начала и конец занятия) и есть текущее время(не строка а время полученое с Date) например 07:50, дак вот каким способом можно реализовать сравнивание времени то есть 07:50 < 08:15 или
07:50 == 08:15 или 07:50 > 08:15. То есть мне нужно проверять прошло ли время(со строки), равняется или еще не наступило по отношению к текущему времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Разбить строку на даты.
2. Получить из даты время в миллисекундах от 1.1.1970
3. Сравнить с текущим.

```
String myDate = "08:15-09:50";
String[] myDates = myDate.split("-");
long myDateInMillisFirst = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(myDates[0]);
long myDateInMillisSecond = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(myDates[1]);

long currentSystemTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("first>currentSystemTimeInMillis: " + myDateInMillisFirst > currentSystemTimeInMillis );
```

Answer (score 1):

В языке Java имеется класс Time. Можно написать

```
System.out.println(Time.valueOf("07:50:00").before(Time.valueOf("08:50:00")
```

А также есть класс Date.

```
 String inputDate = "10/10/2011 07:50:00 AM";
    Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").parse(inputDate);    
    date1.compareTo(date2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Читайте документацию : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

```
Date time1("MM:DD:YYYY:HH:MM:SS"), time2("MM:DD:YYYY:HH:MM:SS");

time1.after(time2); //bool
time1.before(time2); //bool
time1.compateTo(time2); //int (0,-1,1)
```

Советую использовать для времени класс Date или Time, а для даты GregorianCalendar. Таким образом ты разграничишь время и дату, чтобы можно было бы управлять видом даты, полезно для интернационализации.